# Scene Kit Scale Model

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, game-engine, scenekit

I am trying to build a Tower Defense game in SceneKit. I am adding a model into my tile on map, but it is never created in correct position. I use a custom model and scale it.

[image]

```
+ (BasicAttackTower *)CreateTower { // return a single tower
    SCNScene * towerScene = [SCNScene sceneNamed:@"basicattacktower.dae"];
    SCNNode * node =[towerScene.rootNode childNodeWithName:@"SketchUp" recursively:NO ];
    SCNAction * action = [SCNAction rotateByX:0 y:0 z:10 duration:1];
    SCNAction * repeatAction = [SCNAction repeatActionForever:action];
    for(int i=1;i<[node.childNodes count]-1;i++){
        [[node.childNodes objectAtIndex:i] runAction:repeatAction];
    }

    node.scale = SCNVector3Make(0.04, 0.04, 0.04);
    BasicAttackTower * tower = [BasicAttackTower node];
    [tower addChildNode:node];
    return tower;
}

- (void)AddTower:(Tower *)tower {// add tower on tile 
    tower.position = SCNVector3Make((self.position.x), (self.position.y), 2);
    [self addChildNode:tower];
    self.towerOnTile = tower;
}
```

Comment: You don't seem to be calling `-AddTower:`. But even if you did, every tower would be given the same position.

Comment: I use addtower method into tile . In this map i have 100 tile more less . Tower should be created at same position with tile

Comment: Is `self` the tile? If you are adding the tower to the center of the tile, you should use the position (0, 0, 2). A nodes position is relative to it's parent.

Comment: Yes self is the tile . I know but it seems to be tower created different position and i think the reason is scaling but i couldnt figure that out